# How to pass the api client credentials for stackexchange api in python

Tags: support, authentication, python, quota

I am trying to make a console based client, that consumes the stackexchange api. I have done the registration of my app, in order to enjoy higher quotas and received the necessary keys.

My problem is, that I cannot find a page that describes how the app is supposed to pass those credentials. I am using python, if it matters. Could you please shed some light?

Comment: The question a bit fuzzy. Do you just want to enjoy a higher quota?  If so, merely [include the `key` in each API request](https://stackapps.com/a/6962/7653).  Or do you want the app to be able to vote, write posts, access the user's inbox, etc? (All require authentication, while a key does not.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How to increase app request quota from 300 to 10,000*](https://stackapps.com/q/6961/) and/or [*API Implicit Authentication with Python*](https://stackapps.com/q/2903/).

Comment: I am going with @BrockAdams. I need to pass the key to akk my requests. thank you both for the clarifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BrockAdams mentioned, this can be achieved by passing the key to all the sent requests.